# Is there a way to expose the pager fields?

Tags: paging, views

I'd like to let the user pick how many items are gonna be displayed on the page. Therefore, I need to display a field with a select or something.

Is there a way to make that directly through the UI, not with coding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

In the pager settings for the View, select to expose the number of items to the user.

[image]

Make sure the textfield with available items per page options includes the default number of items per page.

Comment: Is this in Drupal 7 ? When I click on the pager options I have only a choice on how what to display (all items, a defined number of item, etc.). If I choose one and then apply, I can only pick the number of items to display and at what number to start. [link](http://i46.tinypic.com/14df1ab.jpg)

Comment: Yes, that's in Drupal 7, choose which type of pager ( e.g full ), then after that you can set the pager options.

Comment: I had not picked the right option. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Don't Forget in your View under 'Advanced' tab to change value of "Use AJAX" item to "Yes" Otherwise it doesn't show view exposed pager

thanx